# Populating choices in an ASP.NET ComboBox from web.config

Tags: asp.net, combobox, web-config

There are several answered questions detailing how to refer to a single value from `web.config` file.  I'd like to maintain lists of values with which to populate combo boxes in the Views.  Should I use some sort of key/value pair structure, with the key identifying the particular combo box to populate?

```
<add key="CalculationMethod" value="Fixed"/>
<add key="CalculationMethod" value="Cost Plus"/>
<add key="CalculationMethod" value="Formula"/>
```

I'm not sure how I'd read this, or if that would even work (don't keys have to be unique?).  The IntelliSense for `web.config` doesn't seem to allow much in the `appSettings` section that looks applicable to a more robust structure like

```
<list name="CalculationMethod">
    <item value="Fixed"/>
    <item value="Cost Plus"/>
    <item value="Formula"/>
</list>
```

I see that the root `<configuration>` has a lot of options for children, but which one to use, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be using a database for something like this but if you must put it in the web.config then you could delimit the values and parse them out at run time.

```
<add key="CalculationMethod" value="Fixed,Cost Plus,Formula"/>

myComboBox.DataSource = new List<String>(lstrCalcMethodsFromWebConfig.Split(','));
```

Comment: I realize this gets into the taboo area of subjectivity, but why do you say I should be putting these sort of things in a database?

Comment: You would normally create a lookup table for something like this so you can be consistent across your applications/codebase.  What happens when someone asks to change `Fixed` to `Actual Fixed`?  In your current design, you would have to change the web.config with the new value and then go update all the records in your database table(s).  If you had it normalized in the database, you change it once in the lookup table and you're done.